# document.write is not working for this block

Tags: javascript, document

I have this block:

```
document.write('<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_computer" alt="POS Computer">POS Computer</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/touch_monitor" alt="Touch Monitor">Touch Monitor</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/receipt_printer" alt="POS Receipt Printer">POS Receipt Printer</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/cash_drawers" alt="Cash Drawer">Cash Drawer</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pole_display" alt="Pole Display">Pole Display</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_accessories/88003_002" alt="Fingerprint Scanner">Fingerprint Scanner</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_computer/fz43_mc2_ald" alt="Mobile POS">Mobile POS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/network/mbr900" alt="3G Backup">3G Backup</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/restaurant_pos_software" alt="Restaurant POS Software">Restaurant POS Software</a></li>
        <li><a href="/software/aldelo/easy.html" alt="Easy To Use">Easy To Use</a></li>
        <li><a href="/software/aldelo/bar_tabs.html" alt="Bar Tabs">Bar Tabs</a></li>
        <li><a href="/software/aldelo/multilingual.html" alt="Multilingual Capable">Multilingual Capable</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/point-of-sale-software/413614" alt="Quickbooks Integration">Quickbooks Integration</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/point-of-sale-software/liquor_monitor" alt="Liquor Monitor Capable">Liquor Monitor Capable</a></li>
        <li><a href="/software/aldelo/reservations.html" alt="Reservations">Reservations</a></li>
        <li><a href="/software/aldelo/training_mode.html" alt="Training Mode">Training Mode</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Integrated Payments">Integrated Payments</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/products.htm" alt="Fast Transactions">Fast Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/merchant-reports.htm" alt="Reduced Errors">Reduced Errors</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/products.htm" alt="Secure Transactions">Secure Transactions</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/gift-cards.htm" alt="Fee Free Gift Cards">Fee Free Gift Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Free 24/7 Support">Free 24/7 Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/merchants.htm" alt="Competetive Pricing">Competetive Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Get a Free Quote">Get a Free Quote</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad lastUnit">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://posnation.com" alt="Free Expert Consultations">Free Expert Consultations</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pos_systems/" alt="Plug & Play POS System">Plug & Play POS System</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pos_support_page" alt="24/7 Support">24/7 Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pos_live_time" alt="Live Training">Live Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/training_dvds" alt="DVD Training">DVD Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pos_urgent" alt="Urgent Care Warranty">Urgent Care Warranty</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_services" alt="Onsite Installation">Onsite Installation</a></li>
        <li><a href="/shop_pos/" alt="Local Touch - Online Prices">Local Touch - Online Prices</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>');
```

…that is not displaying with document.write but this one:

```
document.write('Hey there');
```

…works well. What's the difference and why does the big block not work?

Comment: Please post code snippets in your question. Linking to jsfiddle is a nicety.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multi-line strings must end each line with `\`.

Here's the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pSpHb/1/

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not support [multiline strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript), that's why the example doesn't work for you.

You would be better off using something like [`createDocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) to get where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

because js expects one-line-functions if these lines don't end with `'+ [new line]'`

try this one

```
   document.write('<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">'+
        '<ul>'+
'   <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_computer" alt="POS Computer">POS Computer</a></li>'+
' <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/touch_monitor" alt="Touch Monitor">Touch Monitor</a></li>'+
'<li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/receipt_printer" alt="POS Receipt Printer">POS Receipt Printer</a></li>'+
   '<li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/cash_drawers" alt="Cash Drawer">Cash Drawer</a></li>'+
            '<li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pole_display" alt="Pole Display">Pole Display</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_accessories/88003_002" alt="Fingerprint Scanner">Fingerprint Scanner</a></li>'+
'     <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/pos_computer/fz43_mc2_ald" alt="Mobile POS">Mobile POS</a></li>'+
'    <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_hardware/network/mbr900" alt="3G Backup">3G Backup</a></li>'+
    '</ul>'+
    '</div>'+

    '<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">'+
'  <ul>'+
'      <li><a href="/restaurant_pos_software" alt="Restaurant POS Software">Restaurant POS Software</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/software/aldelo/easy.html" alt="Easy To Use">Easy To Use</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/software/aldelo/bar_tabs.html" alt="Bar Tabs">Bar Tabs</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/software/aldelo/multilingual.html" alt="Multilingual Capable">Multilingual Capable</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/shop_pos/point-of-sale-software/413614" alt="Quickbooks Integration">Quickbooks Integration</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/shop_pos/point-of-sale-software/liquor_monitor" alt="Liquor Monitor Capable">Liquor Monitor Capable</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/software/aldelo/reservations.html" alt="Reservations">Reservations</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/software/aldelo/training_mode.html" alt="Training Mode">Training Mode</a></li>'+
'  </ul>'+
    '</div>'+

    '<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad">'+
' <ul>'+
'    <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Integrated Payments">Integrated Payments</a></li>'+
'  <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/products.htm" alt="Fast Transactions">Fast Transactions</a></li>'+
'   <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/merchant-reports.htm" alt="Reduced Errors">Reduced Errors</a></li>'+
' <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/products.htm" alt="Secure Transactions">Secure Transactions</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/gift-cards.htm" alt="Fee Free Gift Cards">Fee Free Gift Cards</a></li>'+
'     <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Free 24/7 Support">Free 24/7 Support</a></li>'+
'    <li><a href="http://www.mercurypay.com/merchants.htm" alt="Competetive Pricing">Competetive Pricing</a></li>'+
'  <li><a href="/mercury/" alt="Get a Free Quote">Get a Free Quote</a></li>'+
        '</ul>'+
    '</div>'+

    '<div class="sz1of4 unit sm-quad lastUnit">'+
' <ul>'+
'  <li><a href="http://posnation.com" alt="Free Expert Consultations">Free Expert Consultations</a></li>'+
'    <li><a href="/pos_systems/" alt="Plug & Play POS System">Plug & Play POS System</a></li>'+
'     <li><a href="/pos_support_page" alt="24/7 Support">24/7 Support</a></li>'+
'      <li><a href="/pos_live_time" alt="Live Training">Live Training</a></li>'+
'<li><a href="/training_dvds" alt="DVD Training">DVD Training</a></li>'+
' <li><a href="/pos_urgent" alt="Urgent Care Warranty">Urgent Care Warranty</a></li>'+
'   <li><a href="/shop_pos/pos_services" alt="Onsite Installation">Onsite Installation</a></li>'+
'  <li><a href="/shop_pos/" alt="Local Touch - Online Prices">Local Touch - Online Prices</a></li>'+
'</ul>'+
    '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one has a (literal) new line in the middle of a string. You can't do that in JS.